# Chamar função js dentro de outra e dependendo do resultado parar a execução da função pai

Tags: javascript

Bom, tenho uma função(1) com validações em js, gostaria de chama-la dentro de outra função(2) js e caso e a função um tenha um resultado, gostaria de parar a execução da função 2
Por exemplo:

```
function validarCamposSimulador() {
if (form_alterar.opcoes.value == "Selecione...") {
    alert("Selecione um Tipo de Empréstimo!");  
    form_alterar.opcoes.focus();
    return false;
}
if (form_alterar.salario_bruto.value == "0,00" || form_alterar.salario_bruto.value == "") {
    alert("Digite seu Salário Bruto");  
    form_alterar.salario_bruto.focus();
    return false;
}
if (form_alterar.desconto.value == "") {
    alert("Digite um Desconto");    
    form_alterar.desconto.focus();
    return false;
}
if (form_alterar.salario_liquido.value == "0,00" || form_alterar.salario_liquido.value == "") {
    alert("Digite seu Salário Liquido");    
    form_alterar.salario_liquido.focus();
    return false;
}
if (form_alterar.valor_sol.value == "0,00" || form_alterar.valor_sol.value == "") {
    alert("Digite o Valor a ser Solicitado");   
    form_alterar.valor_sol.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

Agora dentro dessa função eu gostaria de chamar a anterior

```
$("#btn_emp").click(function(){
        var valor_maximo = $("#val_max").val();
        var valor_sol = $("#valor_sol").val();
        var valor_entrada = $("#valor_entrada").val();
        var data_inicio = $("#data_inicio").val();
        var prazo = $("#prazo").val();
        data_inicio = data_inicio.replace("/", "-");
        data_inicio = data_inicio.replace("/", "-");
        var auxiliar;
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "../calcularEmprestimo.asp",
          data: { v_sol: valor_sol, v_ent: valor_entrada, prz: prazo,  val_max: valor_max, dt_ini: data_inicio },
          success: function(response) {
           document.getElementById("parcela_inicial").value = response; 
          }
        });
```

Comment: Juntei uma resposta também. Vi o teu edit mas não percebi qual é a função que deve chamar qual... queres chamar `validarCamposSimulador` dentro da callback do `click` e parar caso não funcione, é isso?

Comment: Thiago, alguma das respostas em baixo resolveu o teu problema? Se sim podes clicar para marcar como aceite. Se não diz, para explicarmos melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn_emp").click(function(){
  if (!validarCamposSimulador()) {
     return false;
  }
  var valor_maximo = $("#val_max").val();
  //...
});
```

porém, para isso, você precisa que a função retorne TRUE caso esteja tudo okay:

```
function validarCamposSimulador() {
if (form_alterar.opcoes.value == "Selecione...") {
    alert("Selecione um Tipo de Empréstimo!");  
    form_alterar.opcoes.focus();
    return false;
}
if (form_alterar.salario_bruto.value == "0,00" || form_alterar.salario_bruto.value == "") {
    alert("Digite seu Salário Bruto");  
    form_alterar.salario_bruto.focus();
    return false;
}
//..

 return true;//no final de tudo, fora de todos os ifs
}
```

Comment: Ola Willian, obrigado pela resposta. Uma das dúvidas é justamente como fazer a condição do if, pois ele é um js de validações e caso caia em algum dos ifs dele, ele retorna false. Ah, sou seu fã, sempre vejo suas respostas em forúms, me ajuda muito no trabalho, obrigado duplamente hahaha

Comment: Oi Thiago!
então, a sua função exemplo precisa retornar true ou false.

function exemplo {
  if( algum problema) {
    return true;
  }
  return false
}

se você quiser falar mais concretamente qual o problema, creio que vai ser mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com meu código

Comment: editei minha resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, e parabéns pelo livro de node, ficou ótimo

Answer (score 2):

Para isso a função `exemplo` tem de retornar algo para ser analisado.

Há dois modelos, síncrono e assíncrono.

## Sincrono:

```js
function soNumeros(dados) {
  if (String(dados).match(/^\d+$/)) return true;
  else return false;
}

function exe(algo) {
  var numeroValido = soNumeros(algo);
  if (numeroValido) {
    console.log('Sim!', algo, 'é numero');
  } else {
    console.log('Não!', algo, 'não é numero');
  }
}

[1, 2, 'texto', '3'].forEach(function(teste) {
  exe(teste);
});
```

## Assíncrono

Aqui podes fazer com callbacks, ou Promises:

#### Callback:

```js
function soNumeros(dados, done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (String(dados).match(/^\d+$/)) done(true);
    else done(false);
  }, Math.random() * 2000);
}

function exe(algo) {
  soNumeros(algo, function(numeroValido) {
    if (numeroValido) {
      console.log('Sim!', algo, 'é numero');
    } else {
      console.log('Não!', algo, 'não é numero');
    }
  });
}

[1, 2, 'texto', '3'].forEach(function(teste) {
  exe(teste);
});
```

#### Promises:

```js
function soNumeros(dados, done) {
  return new Promise(function(passa, falha) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (String(dados).match(/^\d+$/)) passa();
      else falha();
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
  });

}

function exe(algo) {
  soNumeros(algo).then(function() {
    console.log('Sim!', algo, 'é numero');
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log('Não!', algo, 'não é numero');
  });
}

[1, 2, 'texto', '3'].forEach(function(teste) {
  exe(teste);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, não foi a solução que usei(usei a da resposta abaixo), mas me mostrou como fazer outras partes do meu código, Abraços